# please explain me what is written here: awk

Tags: bash, awk

In general it should work like that: find all build in job's folder which are older than 30 days and remove builds if their amounts greater than 30.
(remove is not included here). I am just wandering only about awk statement: vRS, vORS options, array statement here and asort function. How it works here?

```
find -type d -name "builds" -mtime +30 -printf "%T@ %p\0" |\
awk -vRS="\0" -vORS="\0" '{match($0,/([^ ]* )(.*)/,a);b[a[2]]=a[1];c[a[1]]=a[2]}END{x=asort(b);for(i=x-30;i>0;i--)print c[b[i]]}' |\
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Details

The option `-vRS="\0"` could be separated into `-v RS="\0"` and sets the variable RS (input record separator) to the value `"\0"` which represents the null byte, so the input records are terminated by a null, consistent with the `-printf` output from `find`.  Similarly, the output record separator, ORS, is set to null by the `-vORS="\0"`, instead of the more normal newline.

The GNU `find` manual explains [time directives](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Time-Directives) and [time formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Time-Formats); the `-T@` means print the modification time of the file in seconds since The Epoch, and the `%p` means print the pathname to the file.  So, the input is a list of time stamps and build times.

The `match()` operation splits the input record into two fields in array `a` — time and name.  For many purposes, `a[1]` would be better written `$1` and `a[2]` would be better written `$2`.  However, the reason it is written as shown is to handle blanks and the like within file names.  The array `b` ends up with the time indexed by pathname; the array `c` ends up with the pathname indexed by time.

The GNU Awk [`asort()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions) function sorts the array `b` in situ (given a single argument — there are other ways of invoking it), reindexing the array with integer subscripts starting from 1, and returning the number of rows in the array.  The loop at the end then prints the oldest build records, leaving 30 names unprinted (because of the `x-30`).  So, it generates all but the most recent 30 builds sent to its input.  It will list nothing if there are not enough old builds around.

#### Summary

Taken altogether, the script generates a list of all the builds over 30 days old except the most recent 30 builds that are over 30 days old.  The names in the output are separated by null bytes.